# Batch file that identifies if a named window is open, and then closes it

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have been using the following script to check if a particular named window is open.

I got it from this thread:-

[How do you test if a window (by title) is already open from the command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29582799/how-do-you-test-if-a-window-by-title-is-already-open-from-the-command-prompt/39862031#39862031)

ideally I will expand the else part to close the window if it is found to be open.

```
@For /f "Delims=:" %A in ('tasklist /v /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq test.bat - Notepad"') do @if %A==INFO (echo Prog not running) else SET "BREX=Awesome" &echo %BREX%
```

Unfortunately when I run this script it returns three instances of my else string?

[image: screenshot]

Is there any way to reduce this down to returning one instance?

Comment: 1. You are setting variable `BREX` *and* reading it in the same command line/block, so you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). 2. `tasklist` returns two header lines, which cause the `for /F` loop to iterate three times; so add the `skip=2` option.

Comment: Just use the /NH option with tasklist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do this with one line from the cmd prompt you can do this.

```
 cmd /v:on /c "@For /f "Delims=:" %A in ('tasklist /v /nh /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq test.bat - Notepad"') do @if %A==INFO (echo Prog not running) else (SET "BREX=Awesome") &echo !BREX!"
```

Or use some conditional execution.

```
tasklist /v /nh /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq test.bat - Notepad" |findstr /B /C:"INFO: No tasks are running">nul && (echo Program not running) || (echo Awesome)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `findstr` instead. You're getting multiple lines of output as you're looping over each line of output

```
tasklist /v /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq test.bat - Notepad" | findstr /C:"No tasks are running" 
if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (
  echo awesome
) else (
  echo Prog not running
)
```

Comment: The /NH option removes the header and will then only output just the match from tasklist.